# How to check if a set of coordinates matches a tetris piece in Python

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, tetris

I’m working with tetris pieces.

The pieces are defined with coordinates, where each piece has an origin block `(0,0)`
So an L piece could be defined as `[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2)]` as well as `[(0,-1), (0,0), (0,1), (1,1)]` depending on where you place the origin block.

**I want to check whether a set of coordinates A e.g. `[(50,50), (50,51), (50,52), (51,52)]`  matches the shape of a given tetris piece B.**

I’m currently using numpy to take away one of the A values from every value in A to reach relative coordinates, then compare with B. The ordering of A will always been in increasing order, but is not guarenteed to match the ordering of B. B is stored in a list with other tetris pieces, and throughout the program, it's origin block will remain the same. This method below seems inefficient and *doesn’t account for rotations / reflections* of B.

```
def isAinB(A,B):  # A and B are numpy arrays
    for i in range(len(A)):
        matchCoords = A - A[i]
        setM = set([tuple(x) for x in matchCoords])
        setB = set([tuple(x) for x in B])
        if setM == setB:  # Sets are used here because the ordering of M and B are not guarenteed to match
            return True
    return False
```

Is there an efficient method / function to implement this? (Accounting for rotations and reflections aswell if possible)

Comment: subtract a threshhold (e,g: the vector of the origin block) from all the coordiantes such that your origin block ends up on [0.0] and then compare with a predefined list of tetris pieces?

Comment: do you care about rotations?

Comment: Besides rotations, do you also want to consider reflections? (traditionally reflections are considered to be different pieces, as in, they have different colors in classic Tetris, but I don't know for you). Importantly, is the order of the given coordinates guaranteed? That is, do they always start in the same "origin" block, and cover the piece in the same relative order?

Comment: @jdehesa Reflections would also help with the solution I'm looking for. The origin block will always be the same for a given piece, and the ordering will be the same. I've elaborated on this in the question to make it more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to approach it. The idea is to first build all the set of variations of a piece in some canonical coordinates (you can do this once per piece kind and reuse it), then put the given piece in the same canonical coordinates and compare.

```
# Rotates a piece by 90 degrees
def rotate_coords(coords):
    return [(y, -x) for x, y in coords]

# Returns a canonical coordinates representation of a piece as a frozen set
def canonical_coords(coords):
    x_min = min(x for x, _ in coords)
    y_min = min(y for _, y in coords)
    return frozenset((y - y_min, x - x_min) for x, y in coords)

# Makes all possible variations of a piece (optionally including reflections)
# as a set of canonical representations
def make_piece_variations(piece, reflections=True):
    variations = {canonical_coords(piece)}
    for i in range(3):
        piece = rotate_coords(piece)
        variations.add(canonical_coords(piece))
    if reflections:
        piece_reflected = [(y, x) for x, y in piece]
        variations.update(make_piece_variations(piece_reflected, False))
    return variations

# Checks if a given piece is in a set of variations
def matches_piece(piece, variations):
    return canonical_coords(piece) in variations
```

These are some tests:

```
# L-shaped piece
l_piece = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
l_piece_variations = make_piece_variations(l_piece, reflections=True)

# Same orientation
print(matches_piece([(50, 50), (50, 51), (50, 52), (51, 52)], l_piece_variations))
# True

# Rotated
print(matches_piece([(50, 50), (51, 50), (52, 50), (52, 49)], l_piece_variations))
# True

# Reflected and rotated
print(matches_piece([(50, 50), (49, 50), (48, 50), (48, 49)], l_piece_variations))
# True

# Rotated and different order of coordinates
print(matches_piece([(50, 48), (50, 50), (49, 48), (50, 49)], l_piece_variations))
# True

# Different piece
print(matches_piece([(50, 50), (50, 51), (50, 52), (50, 53)], l_piece_variations))
# False
```

This is not a particularly smart algorithm, but it works with minimal constraints.

EDIT: Since in your case you say that the first block and the relative order will always be the same, you can redefine the canonical coordinates as follows to make it just a bit more optimal (although the performance difference will probably be negligible and its use will be more restricted):

```
def canonical_coords(coords):
    return tuple((y - coords[0][0], x - coords[0][1]) for x, y in coords[1:])
```

The first coordinate will always be (0, 0), so you can skip that and use it as reference point for the rest, and instead of a `frozenset` you can use a `tuple` for the sequence of coordinates.